# Google analytic crash iOS in different system machine

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

This code was running fine my side but when i switched code to different machine it started crashing

Using Xcode 5

with my custom exception handler i am able to print this

```
2013-12-13 00:50:52.846 Christmas[3236:907] -[GAI logger]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb879440
    2013-12-13 00:50:52.848 Christmas[3236:907] GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: -[GAI logger]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb879440
    2013-12-13 00:50:55.835 Christmas[3236:907] [1] __45-[TServer syncSupportedLangsWithFinishBlock:]_block_invoke [Line 1260] Supported Languages fetched
    2013-12-13 00:50:55.884 Christmas[3236:907] [1] __37-[SearchTransaltionVC syncDataSource]_block_invoke [Line 175] Fetching Data ended
    2013-12-13 00:50:55.885 Christmas[3236:907] [1] __37-[SearchTransaltionVC syncDataSource]_block_invoke [Line 178] Error occurred
    2013-12-13 00:50:55.885 Christmas[3236:907] [1] __37-[SearchTransaltionVC syncDataSource]_block_invoke [Line 179] Error Domain=TServer Code=-1 "user object is requried for fetching details" UserInfo=0xa497230 {NSLocalizedDescription=user object is requried for fetching details}
    2013-12-13 00:50:57.852 Christmas[3236:907] [1] void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 32] CRASH: -[GAI logger]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb879440
    2013-12-13 00:50:57.856 Christmas[3236:907] [1] void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 33] Stack Trace: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x02eb202e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02414e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x02f3d4bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x02ea1bbc ___forwarding___ + 588
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x02ea194e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   Christmas                           0x00002a1e -[TranslatorAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 702
        6   UIKit                               0x01356157 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 266
        7   UIKit                               0x01356747 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1248
        8   UIKit                               0x0135794b -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
        9   UIKit                               0x01368cb5 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1022
        10  UIKit                               0x01369beb -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
        11  UIKit                               0x0135b698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
        12  GraphicsServices                    0x0329cdf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
        13  GraphicsServices                    0x0329cad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x02e27bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x02e27962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x02e58bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x02e57f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x02e57e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        19  UIKit                               0x0135717a -[UIApplication _run] + 774
        20  UIKit                               0x01358ffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
        21  Christmas                           0x0000248c main + 76
        22  Christmas                           0x00002435 start + 53
    )
    2013-12-13 00:50:57.857 Christmas[3236:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GAI logger]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb879440'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2eb2012 0x2414e7e 0x2f3d4bd 0x2ea1bbc 0x2ea194e 0x2a1e 0x1356157 0x1356747 0x135794b 0x1368cb5 0x1369beb 0x135b698 0x329cdf9 0x329cad0 0x2e27bf5 0x2e27962 0x2e58bb6 0x2e57f44 0x2e57e1b 0x135717a 0x1358ffc 0x248c 0x2435)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 1):

This crash has absolutely nothing to do with Google Analytics. Google Analytics is just logging the uncaught exception. Start with the third line - `TServer` and go from there

Answer (score 0):

I just followed these steps again and again and got succeeded, but it was really painful..

1. Removed google analytic sdk first added again, manually added all files.
2. Added/rechecked for required framework  core foundation,dyxlib
3. cleaned project
4. Restarted xcode